# How I can print 'process status' in Django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-views, progress

In one of my views I have several steps and they use 5 or 7 minutes to finish totally, so I was wondering if there is a way to print the status of the view in the browser, like:

"Calculating models..."
"Post processing models..."
"Making DB..."
"Cleaning old tables..."

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Such heavy duty should probably not be part of a django view. You might want to look into [django celery](http://ask.github.com/django-celery/) for asynchronous task management.

However you can do something like that just fine by polling your server. The easy setup, use [short polling](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/) (basically a javascript loop that triggers an ajax request to the server every i seconds, retrieving a status response* which you can use to show your user anything).

**You'll have to setup an url and function that calculates the status somehow or if you're using celery you can use it's asynchronous result*

Comment: Could you please make a complete example for those of us who are just starting web-dev and are not familiar with polling / ajax? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537647/django-post-form-with-status-view-ajax/44538429?noredirect=1#comment76069033_44538429